# How to add a python callback to pointdrawtool

Tags: python, callback, bokeh

fairly new to python/bokeh so apologies. I'm trying to use the pointdrawtool to add arrows to my figure on a bokeh server generated plot. I can add it by making it add invisible circles which share the same columndatasource and therefore arrows are drawn but I then want to adjust the arrow start points via a callback so that they are arrows rather than just triangles.

I've tried various things I've seen here and elsewhere but I've so far failed. I don't have a good understanding of what can and cannot produce a callback. If there's a better simpler way of doing it then that would be fine too.

```py
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.layouts import layout, row, column
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, save, reset_output
from bokeh.models import Label, BoxAnnotation, CustomJS, Slider, Button, ColumnDataSource, BoxEditTool, FreehandDrawTool,PointDrawTool, Arrow, NormalHead
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import webbrowser as wb
def make_document(doc):
    try:
        #set the dimensions for the plot
        x_start=1600
        x_end=2530
        y_start=1800
        y_end=5300
        #### set up figure
        p = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=600, x_range=(x_start,x_end),
        y_range=(y_end,y_start), tools="pan, wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset, undo,
        redo")
        #### set up annotation color and thickness:
        thick_ann=10.0
        col_ann="yellow"
        alpha_ann=0.7
        ### source dataset and associated code for for any added arrows 
        #source_ar=ColumnDataSource( {"xs":[0,0],"ys":[0,3],"xe":[1,1], "ye":[1,4]})
        source_ar=ColumnDataSource( {"xs":[],"ys":[],"xe":[], "ye":[]})
        a1=Arrow(end=NormalHead(size=thick_ann*3, fill_color=col_ann, line_color=col_ann, line_alpha=alpha_ann, fill_alpha=alpha_ann),x_start='xs', y_start='ys', x_end='xs', y_end='ys', source=source_ar, line_color=col_ann, line_width=thick_ann, line_alpha=alpha_ann)
        p.add_layout(a1)
        ### add invisible circle - use this to add and remove arrows 
        c1=p.circle('xs','ys', size=thick_ann*3,alpha=0.0, source=source_ar)
        artool=PointDrawTool(renderers=[c1])
        p.add_tools(artool)
        #### example callback I think I want to run when adding an arrow via the tool - adjust start
        #### values so is actual arrow
        def arr_callback(attr, old, new):
            source_ar.data["xe"][-1]=source_ar.data["xs"][-1] +5
            source_ar.data["ye"][-1]=source_ar.data["ys"][-1] +5
        #c1.glyph.data_source.on_change('selected',arr_callback)
        doc.add_root(p)
    except:
        server.stop()
apps = {'/': Application(FunctionHandler(make_document))}
server = Server(apps, port=5003)
server.start()
wb.open('http://localhost:5003', new=2)
```

Expected result - add a point which adds an invisible circle, an arrow is also drawn and the start point then adjusted so it is an arrow not a triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know only JS callbacks can be added to the tools in Bokeh in general (CrossHairTool. TapTool, etc...). Unfortunately it is not well documented why some tools doesn't support callbacks at all (like ResetTool or PointDrawTool, etc...). Trying to attach a callback to PointDrawTool gives error.

But if you just want to add a new arrow at each mouse click then another option would be to use e.g. JS callback attached to the plot canvas (see code below for Bokeh v1.0.4). Run the code as `python app.py`

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Arrow, NormalHead, Segment

def make_document(doc):
        p = figure(plot_width = 1000, plot_height = 600, x_range = (0, 10),
        y_range = (0, 6), tools = "pan, wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,undo,redo")
        #### set up annotation color and thickness:
        thick_ann = 10.0
        col_ann = "red"
        alpha_ann = 0.7
        #### source dataset and associated code for for any added arrows
        source = ColumnDataSource(data = {"xs":[1, 2, 3], "ys":[1, 2, 3], "xe":[4, 5, 6], "ye":[1, 2, 3], 'width': [30] * 3, 'color': [col_ann] * 3 })
        a1 = Arrow(end = NormalHead(size = thick_ann * 3, fill_color = col_ann, line_color = col_ann, line_alpha = alpha_ann, fill_alpha = alpha_ann), x_start = 'xs', y_start = 'ys', x_end = 'xe', y_end = 'ye', source = source, line_color = col_ann, line_alpha = alpha_ann)
        s1 = p.segment(x0 = 'xs', y0 = 'ys', x1 = 'xe', y1 = 'ye', color = 'color', source = source)
        p.add_layout(a1)

        code = """  new_x = Number(cb_obj.x);
                    new_y = Number(cb_obj.y);
                    data = {xe: [new_x], ys: [new_y], ye: [new_y]};
                    data['xs'] = [Number(data['xe']) - 3];
                    data['color'] = ['red'];
                    data['width'] = [90];
                    source.stream(data); """
        p.js_on_event('tap', CustomJS(args = dict(source = source), code = code))
        doc.add_root(p)

io_loop = IOLoop.current()
server = Server(applications = {'/': Application(FunctionHandler(make_document))}, io_loop = io_loop, port = 5001)
server.start()
server.show('/')
io_loop.start()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. That would certainly do the job. Do you know how to get the shafts to plot though? I adjusted my code and replaced the "x_end" and "y_end" to "xe" and "ye" in the line of code where the arrow is defined and it still doesn't add the shafts to the plot.

Comment: `Arrow` doesn't officially support `ColumnDataSource` but I added `Segment` as the shaft.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. It's certainly guided me in the right direction. I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I am very new to Bokeh but I wanted to do that this morning and came up with that solution:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, PointDrawTool
from bokeh.events import Tap

output_notebook()

def bkapp(doc):

    p = figure(x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10), width=400, 
               height=400, tools=[])

    source = ColumnDataSource({
             'x': [1, 5, 9], 'y': [1, 5, 9], 'color': ['red', 'green', '                yellow']
             })

    def callback(event):
        source.data["x"].append(event.x)
        source.data["y"].append(event.y)
        print(source.data)

    renderer = p.scatter(x="x", y="y", source=source, color="color", 
                         size=10)
    draw_tool = PointDrawTool(renderers=[renderer], 
                              empty_value='black')
    p.on_event(Tap, callback)

    p.add_tools(draw_tool)
    p.toolbar.active_tap = draw_tool

    doc.add_root(p)

show(bkapp)
```

This is using an embedded server in the Jupyter notebook.
I am just drawing points...

Does this help?